# OO Javascript Question

Tags: javascript

Given the following:

```
var someObject = {};

someObject.prototype.a = function() {

};

someObject.prototype.b = function() {

//How can I call someObject.a in this function?

};
```

How can I call someObject.a from someObject.b? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
someObject.prototype.b = function() {
  this.a();
};
```

However your definition of `someObject` is slightly wrong, it should be:

```
var someObject = function() {};
```

Test script:

```
var someObject = function() {};

someObject.prototype.a = function() {
    alert("Called a()");
};

someObject.prototype.b = function() {
    this.a();
};

var obj = new someObject();
obj.b();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably meant to do this:

```
function Thingy() {
}

Thingy.prototype.a = function() {

};

Thingy.prototype.b = function() {
    this.a();
};

var someObject = new Thingy();
```

It's *constructor functions*, not plain objects, that have a special `prototype` property. The `prototype` of a constructor function is assigned to all objects created with that constructor via the `new` keyword as their underlying prototype, which gives them default properties (which may reference functions, as they do above).